# Returned response error code: 500 - Expo and React

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

Currently new to programming and wanting to start on my first project, however I can't figure out the issue despite going to other sources for answers. As I have seen a lot of answers pointing to, is this an issue with the react-native version? Or is this an issue with the directory?

I'm running react 16.8.3 and expo ^33.0.0, and have started to encounter this problem as soon as I imported a header from .src/components/header. In my command prompt the message "unable to resolve ".src/components/header" from "App.js". If I remove this and the import, the app works fine and loads up on the Expo app on my phone with no issues.

Any help on this would be great, as I'm clueless at the moment.

Comment: I think the path of file is incorrect

Comment: Did you perhaps mean "src/components/header" (without the period), or "./src/components/header" (with a slash after the period)?

Comment: Tried changing it in VS code to both of these and unfortunately still nothing. I have saved the header in the directory C:/Projects/yokkaoProject/src/components/header.

If I keep all of my code in App.js, it seems to work alright. The moment I try making other files and importing them however, it keeps flagging up the error code 500. I've also installed yarn and ran it through that, but unfortunately still don't have any luck.